# How can I put together a SUMIFS in Excel to include an OR?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to put together a calendar of regular payments which will have a date begun, day the money is paid and the date cancelled (if there is one), however I'm struggling with setting up my SUMIFS function.  I've set up an example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1utLJQL9s8TmECN2BlLDgkE_0KGXijLvXaEqDTV0WOkM/edit?usp=sharing).

What I'm trying to do is add the paid value on the day the payment is made, if the date started is less than the date, and only if the date cancelled is empty or the date is before the date cancelled.

List of payments:

```
      A            B          C
1  Payment | Begun      | Cancelled
  ---------+------------+------------
2  £5.00   | 01/01/2016 |
3  £9.00   | 04/01/2016 | 01/02/2016
```

Calendar (that I'd expect):

```
      E          F 
1  Date     | Payment   
  ----------+---------
2  01/01/16 | £5.00
3  02/01/16 | £0.00
4  03/01/16 | £0.00
5  04/01/16 | £9.00
...
33 01/02/16 | £5.00
34 02/02/16 | £0.00
35 03/02/16 | £0.00
36 04/02/16 | £0.00
```

So in this example: £5 should be added on 01/01/16 and 01/02/16, while £9 should be added on 04/01/16 only.

So far in the `F` column I have:

```
=SUMIFS($A$2:$A$3, DAY($B$2:$B$3), "="&DAY(E2), $B$2:$B$3, "<="&E2, $C$2:$C$3, ">="&E2)
```

Comment: Did either of the answers below work for you?  If so please mark as one as correct.  It is something only the person posing the question can do.  Click on the green check mark by the one that is correct, the one you used.

Comment: Apologies - I hadn't got around to checking whether anyone had answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Array formula in F2 should do what you want:

```
=SUM(IF((DAY($B$2:$B$3)=DAY(E2))*(E2>=$B$2:$B$3)*(E2<=$C$2:$C$3),$A$2:$A$3))+SUM(IF((DAY($B$2:$B$3)=DAY(E2))*(E2>=$B$2:$B$3)*(""=$C$2:$C$3),$A$2:$A$3))
```

It is an Array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copied down.

The 'OR' in Array formulas must use a `+`.  If all you had were `AND` the `*` would work.

[image]

I assume you are going to be adding dates to columns A:C, you can change all the small absolute ranges to the desired ranges and it will work for multiples.

Do forgive our backwards dates.

Answer (score 0):

you should just ADD the results of two separate SUMIF()'s in your case:

`=SUMIFS($A$2:$A$3, DAY(B$2:B$3), "="&DAY(E2), $B$2:$B$3, "<="&E2, $C$2:$C$3,">="&E2) 
+ 
SUMIFS($A$2:$A$3, DAY(B$2:B$3), "="&DAY(E2), $B$2:$B$3, "<="&E2, ISBLANK($C$2:$C$3),TRUE)`

Confirm with Ctrl+Shift+enter

Comment: I think the idea of adding is good if the conditions are mutually exclusive, but functions like DAY don't actually work in SUMIFS so it looks as if it might need an array formula solution.

Comment: This is an array Formula.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe, if there's an array formula solution, what would it be?

Comment: Like Scott Craner's. If it's only possible for one payment to come through on a particular day of the month then it could be simplified, otherwise you'd have to put helper columns in for the days to avoid using an array formula.